# How to get rid of Angular2 / TypeScript errors on Cannot find map, Promise ... when targeting -es5?

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, webstorm, angular

How to get rid of Angular2 errors on Cannot find map, Promise ... when targeting -es5

if I target es6 the errors will go away, but I must target es5

I am using Intelij latest version, but even pure tsc will give same errors...

see image

tx for reading

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding typed references manually to es6.d.td