# Cannot find name Promise in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-promise, observable

Used all the below references but still in VS 2015 I'm getting below errors

Cannot find name Promise and 
Property  'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable'

Use Below Imports

import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use **Visual Studio 2015 update 3** and had the same problem.
I changed file

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\typescriptServices.js

with the file from

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/Fix8518-U3/lib/typescriptServices.js

and my problem went away.

[image]
Maybe it helps you too

Comment: Thanks man , Thanks alot..! Awesome , but do we hav eany alternative other than this ? because modifying file is  not suggested one . Can you provide any official reference or site for the proposed solution??  and I still See Cannot Find Promise error (only toPromise is resolved)

Comment: Try to open this project https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-typescript-systemjs in visual studio. Maybe you forgot to configurate typings http://www.ryadel.com/en/visual-studio-2015-fix-typescript-ts2304-compilation-errors/ Check also this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178790/build-cannot-find-name-promise-visual-studio-2015-w-mvc6-and-angular-2